# How to perform mutliplication of negative octal and hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: number-systems

So I am supposed to do these two multiplication problems
(-6*4)<sub>8</sub> and (-7*8)<sub>16</sub>

I did it the same way I would do with positive ones and ended up with the wrong results.

I tried these on a calculator and got the following results respectively
(7777777750)<sub>8</sub> and (FFFFFFFFC8)<sub>16</sub>

Hope someone helps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are converting $-6\times 4=-24$ in base $10$ to base $8$, and $-7\times 8=-56$ to base $16$.

In the first case, we have $-24=-3\times 8$, so 
$$-24_{10}=-30_8$$ 
In the second case we have $-56=-3\times16-8$, so 
$$-56_{10}=-38_{16}$$

These are the right answers, but they do correspond to your calculator's results, except your calculator seems to like doing things modulo $8^{10}$ and $16^{10}$ (perhaps your calculator only has space for $10$ digits): Notice that
$$10000000000_8-30_8=7777777750_8$$
and
$$10000000000_{16}-38_{16}=FFFFFFFFC8_{16}$$